# Fragment does not inflate the layout properly

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, inflate, android-tablelayout

I have a grid which is created using a `TableLayout`. I'm dynamically adding the `TableRows` to the `TableLayout`. I have created the layout as a fragment but when I'm adding that fragment to my `FragmentActivity` it gives me the following error:

```
Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class TodayPriceList extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout llTop = null;
    LinearLayout llPriceList = null;
    RelativeLayout rlPriceTableHeading = null;
    TableLayout priceTableHedaer = null;
    TableLayout tlPriceList = null;
    ScrollView svGridScroll = null;
    TableRow row;
    TextView tvSymbol = null;
    TextView tvSharevolume = null;
    TextView tvOpen = null;
    TextView tvHigh = null;
    TextView tvLow = null;
    TextView tvLastTrade = null;

    TextView symbol,shareVol,open,high,low,lastTrade;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todaypricelist, container, false);
        llTop = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_top);
        llPriceList = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_priceList);
        rlPriceTableHeading = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl_priceTable_heading);
        llPriceList = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ll_priceList);
        tlPriceList = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.priceTable);
        priceTableHedaer = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.priceTableHedaer);
        svGridScroll = (ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.ScrollView11);
        tvSymbol = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSymbol);
        tvSharevolume = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSharevolume);
        tvOpen = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvOpen);
        tvHigh = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvHigh);
        tvLow = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLow);
        tvLastTrade = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLastTrade);

        //fillPriceTable(container);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvSymbol);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvSharevolume);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvOpen);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvHigh);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvLow);
        priceTableHedaer.addView(tvLastTrade);

        //define array data
        String[] dummy=new String[]{"AEL.N000","48.56","16.00","15.00","16.00","18.00"};

        //Converting to dip unit
                int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                        (float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    row=new TableRow(container.getContext());
                    int rowcount=i%2;
                    if(rowcount>0){
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0F8F7"));
                    }
                    symbol = new TextView(container.getContext());
                    //t1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                    shareVol = new TextView(container.getContext());
                    //t2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
                    open=new TextView(container.getContext());
                    high=new TextView(container.getContext());
                    low=new TextView(container.getContext());
                    lastTrade=new TextView(container.getContext());

                    symbol.setText(dummy[0]);
                    shareVol.setText(dummy[1]);
                    open.setText(dummy[2]);
                    high.setText(dummy[3]);
                    low.setText(dummy[4]);
                    lastTrade.setText(dummy[5]);

                    symbol.setWidth(55*dip);
                    shareVol.setWidth(30*dip);
                    open.setWidth(30*dip);
                    high.setWidth(30*dip);
                    low.setWidth(30*dip);
                    lastTrade.setWidth(30*dip);

                    symbol.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    shareVol.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    open.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    high.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    low.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    lastTrade.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


                    symbol.setTextSize(12);
                    shareVol.setTextSize(12);
                    open.setTextSize(12);
                    high.setTextSize(12);
                    low.setTextSize(12);
                    lastTrade.setTextSize(12);

                    symbol.setHeight(20*dip);
                    symbol.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);



                    row.addView(symbol);
                    row.addView(shareVol);
                    row.addView(open);
                    row.addView(high);
                    row.addView(low);
                    row.addView(lastTrade);

                    tlPriceList.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


                }
                rlPriceTableHeading.addView(priceTableHedaer);
         svGridScroll.addView(tlPriceList);
         llPriceList.addView(svGridScroll);
         llTop.addView(rlPriceTableHeading);
         llTop.addView(llPriceList);
     return view;
    }


}
```

Here is my layout.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/ll_top"
     >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_priceTable_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" >
<TableLayout

                    android:id="@+id/priceTableHedaer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:shrinkColumns="*" 
                    android:weightSum="50">

    <TableRow >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvSymbol"
            android:layout_width="70dip"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/symbol"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"

            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSharevolume"
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSymbol"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/sharevolume"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:textStyle="normal"
             >

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOpen"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvSharevolume"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/open"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHigh"
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvOpen"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/high"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLow"
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvHigh"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/low"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLastTrade"
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvLow"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="@string/lastTrad"
            android:textColor="#2E2EFE"
            android:textSize="11dip"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_priceList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

                <TableLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/priceTable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"

                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:shrinkColumns="*" 
                    android:layout_height="50dip">
                </TableLayout>


        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
Here is the updated code which fixed the issue.

```
    public class TodayPriceList extends Fragment {
    TableLayout tlPriceList = null;
    TableRow row;
    TextView tvSymbol = null;
    TextView tvSharevolume = null;
    TextView tvOpen = null;
    TextView tvHigh = null;
    TextView tvLow = null;
    TextView tvLastTrade = null;

    TextView symbol,shareVol,open,high,low,lastTrade;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todaypricelist, container, false);

        tlPriceList = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.priceTable);
        tvSymbol = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSymbol);
        tvSharevolume = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSharevolume);
        tvOpen = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvOpen);
        tvHigh = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvHigh);
        tvLow = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLow);
        tvLastTrade = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLastTrade);


        //define array data
        String[] dummy=new String[]{"AEL.N000","48.56","16.00","15.00","16.00","18.00"};

        //Converting to dip unit
                int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                        (float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                   row = new TableRow(tlPriceList.getContext());
                   int rowcount=i%2;
                    if(rowcount>0){
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E0F8F7"));
                    }
                    symbol = new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());
                    //t1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                    shareVol = new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());
                    //t2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
                    open=new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());
                    high=new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());
                    low=new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());
                    lastTrade=new TextView(tlPriceList.getContext());

                    symbol.setText(dummy[0]);
                    shareVol.setText(dummy[1]);
                    open.setText(dummy[2]);
                    high.setText(dummy[3]);
                    low.setText(dummy[4]);
                    lastTrade.setText(dummy[5]);

                    symbol.setWidth(55*dip);
                    shareVol.setWidth(30*dip);
                    open.setWidth(30*dip);
                    high.setWidth(30*dip);
                    low.setWidth(30*dip);
                    lastTrade.setWidth(30*dip);

                    symbol.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    shareVol.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    open.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    high.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    low.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    lastTrade.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);


                    symbol.setTextSize(12);
                    shareVol.setTextSize(12);
                    open.setTextSize(12);
                    high.setTextSize(12);
                    low.setTextSize(12);
                    lastTrade.setTextSize(12);

                    symbol.setHeight(20*dip);
                    symbol.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);



                    row.addView(symbol);
                    row.addView(shareVol);
                    row.addView(open);
                    row.addView(high);
                    row.addView(low);
                    row.addView(lastTrade);

                    tlPriceList.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


                }

     return view;
    }


}
```

[image: Here is the screen which Im trying to develop using this. Is there any other memory efficient way to develop this than this?]

Comment: delete `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` lines from `TableLayout` declaratoins. This line should be in top layout declaration only.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan Thanks. I did remove the line and edited the question but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow the *Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment* in the logcat should be the explanation of the real problem. The problem is that you use the inflated layout incorrectly and you get in a situation where you add a view that has a parent to the same parent which will throw an `IllegalStateException`(as a view which is in a view hierarchy must first be removed from that hierarchy and then added).

In the `onCreateView` you inflate the layout file and then search for the views. Now for some unknow reason you try to add those views again(which are already in the layout as children of a `TableRow`) to the same parent that they have in the layout, which is wrong.  The same thing you do with the `LinearLayout` at the end of the `onCreateView`, you already have the `ScrollView` added to the `LinearLayout` but then again try to add the same view to the `LinearLayout`, which is wrong.

There is no need to add those view **again** if you have them in the layout, you just have to add the new rows that you construct in that `for` loop.

Also adding 100 `TableRows` with 6 children will not work, you'll kill the app with out of memory exceptions, there will be to many views to render. Use a `ListView` instead if you need that many rows in your layout.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I fixed the issue and it works now. I'll update with the modified code. I know there can be memory issues as you mentioned but to create the required screen I don't have any other way. Listview will not help and also the gridview.I'll think about it. Many Thanks

Comment: @virtualpathum You'll not be able to get 100 `TableRows` in a single layout(with 6 views per row that is about 600 rows, which is way to much as the recommended number of a views in a layout should be under 80). If you have problems adapting the layout to use a `ListView` post a new question with details  and you'll surely get help.

Comment: I just updated the question with an image of the layout which Im going to develop. Appreciate if you could look that. Right now I have 290 records and with this code the table getting populating properly. I didn't check the memory issues yet ;)

Comment: @virtualpathum I don't see how you have 290 rows, that would mean you have more than 1740 views in the layout which is impossible. In order to use a `ListView` you would make a layout containing a `LinearLayout` which will be the header(it will contain all the `TextViews` from the current table header). To make it look as a table you'll use weights to give the `TextViews`  the right amount of space. Then you would use the same layout as the `ListView` row and use a custom adapter with it to bind the data.